# How can I get changes in a directory in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, last-modified

I am trying to get the last change in a directory, not just the last modified file.

I have this code so far:

```py
import pathlib
import logging

# Set logging level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Define some paths
source_path = pathlib.Path("U:")

logging.info(f"Source directory is {source_path}")

# Latest path
latest_path = max(source_path.glob('*'),
                  key=lambda path: path.stat().st_ctime)
last_path = None

while True:
    try:
        # Latest path
        latest_path = max(source_path.glob('*'),
                          key=lambda path: path.stat().st_ctime)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    if not latest_path == last_path:
        logging.info(f"Last changed path is {latest_path}")
        last_path = latest_path
```

What it does it is print out the latest change in the directory (Currently `U:`)

Here's some sample output:

```
INFO:root:Source directory is U:
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:Website Downloader
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:New Text Document.txt <-- Created it
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:hi.txt <-- Renamed it
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:Website Downloader <-- Deleted hi.txt
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:New folder <-- Created it
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:hi <-- Renamed it
INFO:root:Last changed path is U:Website Downloader <-- Deleted hi (directory)
```

It missed stuff such as saving changes in files in base directory (`U:`), new, modified, and deleted files in directories.

I would like for it to say, like:

```
INFO:root:Source directory is U:
INFO:root:File created: U:New Text Document.txt 
INFO:root:File modified: U:New Text Document.txt
INFO:root:File deleted: U:New Text Document.txt
INFO:root:Directory created: U:New Folder
INFO:root:File created: U:New Folder\New Text Document.txt 
INFO:root:File modified: U:New Folder\New Text Document.txt 
INFO:root:File deleted: U:New Folder\New Text Document.txt 
INFO:root:Directory created: U:New Folder\New Folder
INFO:root:Directory created: U:New Folder\New Folder\New Folder
INFO:root:Directory deleted: U:New Folder\New Folder\New Folder
INFO:root:Directory deleted: U:New Folder
```

Is this even possible in Python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I advise you to use a watchdog rather than a custom made solution. You will certainly find example code online. The watchdog or other such library will not be polling but relying on being notified by the operating system on the spot.

Comment: I am going to investigate the watchdog module, but since @alaniwi took the time to produce some working code, I will give him the check mark.

Comment: I am not worried about getting an upvote. I just believe that an event driven solution supported by the OS is a much better solution.

Comment: @Tarik, when did I say about giving upvotes? Please, correct me if I going crazy, but I never said anything about giving upvotes. alaniwi spent precious time answering my question with code, not a link to a module, so I will accept his answer.

Comment: Oh, and I am using the watchdog module right now BTW.

Comment: You brought up the check mark thing more than once and I told you it's not my worry. You somehow felt important to remind me and insist that ready made code made your day and deserved the upmark. So, I am just responding to you that I do not care and I believe that joelhed and I proposed a better quality solution.

Comment: Ahh, okay than. I would have expected you would have responded to my comment below your answer, not here, which is really confusing. Maybe an example usage of the library could've helped a bit, but it doesn't matter now to me. I've already got my code running with your proposed solution. I was just trying to be nice. I apologize if I have offended you.

Comment: Hey, it's ok. At my age I should be wiser that stupidly overreacting. My apologies.

Comment: No, it's ok. I'm sorry for being a bonehead. And I appreciate your answer about the watchdog module. The event-driven code looks and works much better now.

Comment: And, overreacting means that you are passoniate about it. Thats good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, if you *need* to use a polling scanner, here is an implementation.  Subject to the obvious caveats about performance, and it not noticing files that appear and disappear again between poll intervals.

```
import time
import pathlib
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def get_paths(path):
    answer = {}
    for x in pathlib.Path(path).rglob("*"):
        try:
            answer[str(x)] = (x.stat().st_ctime, x.is_dir())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
    return answer


def log(name, is_dir, action):
    descrip = "Directory" if is_dir else "File"
    logging.info("{} {}: {}".format(descrip, action, name))
    

def scan(top_dir, sleep_time):

    old_paths = get_paths(top_dir)
    s_old_paths = set(old_paths)

    while True:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        new_paths = get_paths(top_dir)
        s_new_paths = set(new_paths)
        cre_names = s_new_paths - s_old_paths
        del_names = s_old_paths - s_new_paths

        for name in cre_names:
            _, is_dir = new_paths[name]
            log(name, is_dir, "created")

        for name in del_names:
            _, is_dir = old_paths[name]
            log(name, is_dir, "deleted")

        for name in s_old_paths & s_new_paths:
            new_time, is_dir = new_paths[name]
            old_time, _ = old_paths[name]
            if new_time != old_time:
                log(name, is_dir, "modified")

        old_paths = new_paths
        s_old_paths = s_new_paths
    

top_dir = "U:"
sleep_time = 10
scan(top_dir, sleep_time)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! I will mark this as the correct answer, because it has *actual* code in it and it does what i need

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino You're welcome. I didn't write much of a description, but as you can see, it uses dictionaries of `path_name: (ctime, is_dir)` and just compares the current with the previous one each time. Obviously something event-driven has potential to be a better solution if actually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a folder watcher library that is event driven. For example https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

For more, Google out python folder watcher

It is probably operating system dependant.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I marked @alaniwi's answer as the answer because it has working code, but I will check out the watchdog library!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, I mean, anything is possible! It might be a little complex however, so I'd recommend you use a library like [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/hacking.html), which hooks into the operating system's file system event monitoring thingamabob.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I will check out the watchdog module.

Comment: Also, 1+ for using the scientific term thingamabob.